# jax function "grad" using complex numbers

Tags: python, loss-function, gradient-descent, jax

I am trying to use the jax function "grad". The function to which I want to calculate the gradient is "loss", and its inputs are complex arrays. When I want to run "grad" I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-b455310c3caa> in <module>
----> 1 grads = jax.grad(loss)(params, data.T, Pk, Pk, num_kraus)
      2 grads = jnp.conj(grads)
      3 updated_params = stiefel_update(params, grads, 0.00001)

    [... skipping hidden 6 frame]

~/miniconda3/envs/redes-neuronales/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py in _check_output_dtype_revderiv(name, holomorphic, x)
   1225                       f"but got {aval.dtype.name}.")
   1226   elif dtypes.issubdtype(aval.dtype, np.complexfloating):
-> 1227     raise TypeError(f"{name} requires real-valued outputs (output dtype that is "
   1228                     f"a sub-dtype of np.floating), but got {aval.dtype.name}. "
   1229                     "For holomorphic differentiation, pass holomorphic=True. "

TypeError: grad requires real-valued outputs (output dtype that is a sub-dtype of np.floating), but got complex128. For holomorphic differentiation, pass holomorphic=True. For differentiation of non-holomorphic functions involving complex outputs, use jax.vjp directly.
```

Here, the "loss" functions and the lines of code where I want to calculate its gradient:

```
@partial(jit, static_argnums=4)
def loss(params, data=None, probes=None, measurements=None, num_kraus=None):
    """Loss function for the training assuming a predict function that can 
    generate probabilities for a measurement from the given process representation
    captured in params.

    Args:
        params (array): Parameters to optimize, e.g., Kraus operators.
        data (array): Data representing measured probabilities.
        probes (array): The probe operators.
        measurements (array): The measurement operators as Pauli vectors.
        num_kraus (int): The number of Kraus operators.

    Returns:
        loss (float): A scalar loss
    """
    k_ops = get_unblock(params, num_kraus)
    data_pred = predicta(k_ops, probes, measurements )

    l2 = jnp.sum(((data - data_pred)**2))
    return l2 + 0.001*jnp.linalg.norm(params, 1)
```

```
grads = jax.grad(loss)(params, data.T, Pk, Pk, num_kraus)
grads = jnp.conj(grads)
updated_params = stiefel_update(params, grads, 0.00001)
```

The error message recommends me to use jax.vpn. I tried just replacing "grad" with "vjp". But it informs me that it needs more inputs. I don't know if vjp is going to do exactly what I want, which is to calculate the gradient of the "loss" function. I would like to be able to use the "grad" function with complex numbers.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you say more about what your expected output is? Gradients of complex functions are not well-defined without more information. If your function is [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), you could call `grad` with `holomorphic=True` and it should give you the result you're after. If it's not holomorphic, then you need to put more thought into what you mean by "gradient".

Answer (score 0):

`jax.grad` does not work with complex outputs directly, unless you pass `holomorphic=True`. For example:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x):
  return x ** 2

x = jnp.complex64(1 + 1j)

jax.grad(f)(x)
# TypeError: grad requires real-valued outputs (output dtype that is a sub-dtype of np.floating),
# but got complex64. For holomorphic differentiation, pass holomorphic=True.
# For differentiation of non-holomorphic functions involving complex outputs, use jax.vjp directly.

jax.grad(f, holomorphic=True)(x)
# Array(2.+2.j, dtype=complex64)
```

The reason for this is that the derivative over complex domains cannot be expressed in a single complex number in all cases, however, [holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) are a particular subset of complex functions whose derivatives can be expressed in terms of a single complex number. When you pass `holomorphic=True`, you are telling JAX that it is safe to assume that your function is holomorphic.

See [Autodiff Cookbook: Complex Numbers and Differentiation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html#complex-numbers-and-differentiation) for more discussion of this issue.